# Creating collection in mongodb Atlas

Tags: mongodb, express, mongodb-atlas

Let's say I have the database that contains years such as 2001, 2002, and so on as collections. And each year contains song tracks released from that year whenever the user "adds" it to their playlist. So if I added "Toosie Slide" by Drake to my playlist, the backend code would add "Toosie Slide" to the 2020 collection. But let's say the 2020 collection doesn't exist in the database. Is it possible to automatically create a "2020" collection based on the user adding a song from a year that wasn't already a collection.

And this is using MongoDB Atlas and Express btw.

Answer (score 0):

When you write to a collection, if the collection does not already exist, it will be transparently created in most cases[*]. Typically you do not need to create collections explicitly unless you want to set some collection-wide options like which shard to place the collection on.

[*] Current server versions do not support collection creation in transactions, if you are using a transaction you need to create the collection beforehand.

Comment: So from Express server.js I can create a new collection and then route to it at once? Or does the 2020 collection have to be made beforehand. And also what do you mean by transaction? Is it when the user is interacting with the frontend which interacts with the backend simultaneously?

Comment: The answer already answers the question that you are restating in this comment.

Comment: Ok so if I were to make a new collection automatically from the user's input, can i pass data from a react app front end to the server.js? Such as if i wanted to pass the value "2020" down to make that as a collection in server.js